# DownloadString return 502 bad gateway error from SSIS script task

Tags: ssis, webclient, script-task, downloadstring

I have a webapi from which I am getting JSON data by using WebClient DownloadString method.

When I run the URL in the browser, I get the JSON response, but when I run it using SSIS package, it is failing at DownloadString  call with the following error.

[Download Json] Error: Download failed: The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.

The code I have is

```
 using (var mySSISWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                mySSISWebClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
                var result = mySSISWebClient.DownloadString(jsonURL);
            }
```

The actual text I get when I enter that jsonURL in browser is

```
 {"SEARCHRESPONSE":{"STATUS":"failed","SEARCHTERM":"*:*","SUGGESTION":"","DESCRIPTION":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Error</title>\n<style>\n    body {\n        width: 35em;\n        margin: 0 auto;\n        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;\n    }\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h1>An error occurred.</h1>\n<p>Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.<br/>\nPlease try again later.</p>\n<p>If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check\nthe error log</a> for details.</p>\n</body>\n</html>\n"}}
```

Please help me finding the cause.